# The Volume/Sound of Youtube videos in my main Youtube account is lower than the other youtube accounts

Tags: google-chrome, audio, youtube

I have 3 different youtube accounts but for some reason, the volume/sound of one of them is lower than the other two accounts.

The system sound is working well. So the main problem is the youtube account because the volume of my first youtube account is lower than the other two.

Any Solution for this?

Comment: Man, I have same issue for many months already. Different accounts sound different with all other settings the same.

Answer (score -1):

I just encountered this issue recently and was able to fix it.

Not sure if it's the same case for you but the channel that was affected for me was a "Brand account" that I wasn't the primary owner of.
(This was because I made the channel years ago with a different email and never bothered to transfer ownership.)

I transferred the ownership to my current email and transferred the account back to a normal personal Email account from a brand account and it solved the issue for me.

If you want to try this out just a word of warning:

When you are transferring the account back to a normal Email account it will replace the one already on that email and delete that channel (YouTube will also warn you of this but I thought I would mention it). This wasn't a problem for me as I never used that account.

If you do use that channel and don't want it to be deleted I would suggest making a new email or using an alternative one with a YouTube channel that you don't use and making that account the primary owner of the "Brand account" (The one with the audio problems) and then transfer the Brand account into that email.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

This might be a messy answer so apology's, I just brainstormed what I could think of and not being systematic at all, it's a little to late at night for that :).

I would start by making a list of all possible volume changing options available. Meaning, try to find every volume slider able to affect chrome, making sure all three profiles, when loaded have the same value.

Do you start chrome first and then select a profile or do you have three different scripts starting with command flags. If so, I'd check the flags first and rule those out.
Then I'd check the browser extensions to see if they could be the culprit.
And also check the "site settings" (Where you set the defaults what any page have direct access to or have to ask you for permission before accessing system resources.
Do you have any pinned tabs in the naughty profile and if so try closing those.
I'd also check if there's any accessibility settings activated. Or any extra hardware/software turned on for that profile. I'm thinking microphones and recording software like OBS.
Does your desktop treat your browser as three different browsers or just the one. Maybe the faulty one gets a different sound device assigned to it than the others, like 2.1 (two fronts and a sub) instead of 4.1 like the others.

If you have a program that displays a visual representation of the volume, try to compare the profiles to see if the level looks like it's the same even though there's a volume difference.
Are you using a VPN on the profile and therefor connect to different servers?
There might be a "allow exceeding 100% volume" that is enabled on the other two profiles.
If you create a new profile, how's the volume then?

How different are the profiles? Just three different names or different input settings as well (Like languages). If you have a keyboard with a volume knob on perhaps one input type loads with a different setting.
Have you tried to clear the browser cache and delete all youtube cookies?
If you sync to any cloud you could try to delete the profile and re-create it. (Don't forget to sync first)
Is that specific profile also used on any other device like your phone?
Is there any experimental flags set that could mess up the sound? (chrome://flags)
As a last resort I'd export all passwords and all bookmarks locally and reinstall chrome. If you do this, first try to recreate all profiles with the locally exported stuff *without* connecting them to the cloud first to see if  there's any foul play going on when syncing.

And yeah, that's all I could come up with I think. And again, apologies for the messy answer and good luck to you Sir!